# Angular 5 Path param

Tags: angular, url, parameters, path, observable

I want to get Path param on state  and get user from my API with this param.

I have tried something by looking this angular guide : [Route parameters in the ActivatedRoute service](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service)

But this is not working.

The link that route page :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/users', user.id]" > Person </a>
```

this is the component which I want to get id on :

```
export class UserManagementViewComponent implements OnInit {

  user$: Observable<User>;


  constructor(private userManagementService:UserManagementService,private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.get();
  }

  get(){

    this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
          return this.userManagementService.get(+params.get("id"))

          }
      )

  }
```

this is the get function on my service :

```
public get(id:number):Observable<User>{
    let url = this.apiUrl+ "/admin/user/" + id;
    return this.http.get<User>(url);
  }
```

And this is the template that shows incoming user : (template of UserManagementViewComponent):

```
<div class="card-content grey-text">
        <span class="card-title">{{(user$  | async)?.name}}'s Profile</span>
        <hr class="seperate">

    <ul>
      <li>name : {{(user$ | async)?.name}}</li>
      <li>surname : {{(user$  | async)?.surname}}</li>
      <li>username : {{(user$ | async)?.username}}</li>
      <li>email : {{(user$  | async)?.email}}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

the error I am getting is :

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(3,28): error TS6143: Module './Observable' was resolved to '/home/sam/git/jwt-spring-security-and-angular/web-ui/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/IfObservable.d.ts(1,51): error TS6143: Module '../Observable' was resolved to '/home/sam/git/jwt-spring-security-and-angular/web-ui/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/do.d.ts(1,28): error TS6143: Module '../Observable' was resolved to '/home/sam/git/jwt-spring-security-and-angular/web-ui/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.d.ts(1,28): error TS6143: Module '../Observable' was resolved to '/home/sam/git/jwt-spring-security-and-angular/web-ui/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMap.d.ts(1,45): error TS6143: Module '../Observable' was resolved to '/home/sam/git/jwt-spring-security-and-angular/web-ui/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
```

What is the problem, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that 'Observable' is resolving to a .js file instead of a .ts file. Check your imports.

Comment: import declaration is correct
 (import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';)
but it doesn't redirect to source when I click it.
Could it be deleted? if it is, how can I fix this library?

Comment: As a first shot, try deleting your node_modules directory, and then do an "npm install". If that doesn't help, post the contents of your package.json file here.

Comment: yes that solved the errors thanks, there is nothing any error now, but user still does not come to view.I am sure that service work fine.

Comment: yes that works fine now, i  changed some code when i get error. i get back the code as my post. it is working now. Thanks a lot.